# Einstein Apex AI Tools Visibility/Unavailability

Tags: einstein

I have recently read an article on Einstein Apex AI Tools in [Salesforce developer blog](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2019/06/get-buildspiration-with-einstein-apex-ai-tools.html). The article shows how to extract text form image using Apex-AI-Tools in apex code. But when I tried to implement that in an apex class, I got an error saying 
Error: 'Type is not visible: AITools.MLServices'

I have searched but didn't found a solution. Can anyone help me to overcome the error ?

[image: Einstein Apex AI Tools not visible]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got an answer form a person that the `Einstein` `Apex AI Tool` is currently in `Pilot` stage. As a result it's still not available to use. Hope we can use the awesome tool in the `next release`  !!